# SAPUI5 Block searchfield while request is running

Tags: search, sapui5, blocking

I am using CSRF tokens to secure my requests. During the request roundtrip, the UI is blocked by using a global busy indicator:

```
sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show();
```

When a user enters a search term quickly, the blocking does not react fast enough and the second request is fired without the first having been returned. So the wrong CSRF token gets sent. Is there a nice and easy way how to prevent the search field from processing liveChange events as long as a roundtrip is going on?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the busy indicator delay isn't blocking the UI fast enough?

Have you tried setting the busy indicator delay to 0?

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/setBusyIndicatorDelay

Comment: Exactly, I added the call to set the global indicator in my question. How can the delay set in my case?

Comment: @AntonSack in your case `sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(0);`